# how can i install Boost 1.55 on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: libraries

How can i install, from packages, Boost 1.55 on Ubuntu 15.10? For example, the repository (via Synaptic) only shows Boost 1.58 only, and Emulationstation (the version i have as tarball) uses Boost 1.55 as dependency - i have 1.58 installed, and terminal shows "emulationstation: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

This can be really bad for your system. 
The best thing to do is to clone the source code and compile it yourself.

(it doesn't look that hard: https://github.com/Aloshi/EmulationStation)

But if for some reason you really want to install an old version of libboost you can do it that way:
(I really **don't** recommend doing that unless you know what you're doing, 
**you can damage** your system)
Download from here the packages suitable for your OS: 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.55/

Ror 64bit download `libboost1.55-dev_1.55.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb` 
 For 32bit download `libboost1.55-dev_1.55.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2_i386.deb`
If you run something else download `libboost1.55-doc_1.55.0+dfsg-3ubuntu2_all.deb`

Answer (score 0):

If it's available in your current `apt` sources, you can install it using the below steps:

1. Press CTRL+ALT+T
2. Type `sudo apt-get install libboost1.55*`
3. If prompted type in your password (When you type in your password nothing will show up, this is normal)
4. If prompted type `y` to confirm that you want to install it.
5. Profit! If all went well, then congrats! You successfully installed it!

Comment: i tried "sudo apt-get install libboost*=1.55" and said "E: Version '1.55' for 'libboost(...)' was not found"

Comment: Got it! Look at the updated answer!

Comment: i think that didn’t work because 1.55 isn’t there in the repository, only 1.58, which doesn’t work - perhaps i need to add the repository from a previous ubuntu version, or maybe create file links of 1.58 renamed as 1.55? or perhaps adding a ppa from somewhere? which is the best approach?

Comment: I know, that's why I suggested the above. The above _is_ available from the default sources

Comment: i tried that, but that is going to install the missing libboost1.58*, not libboost1.55*

Answer (score -1):

This will cover the bases for you:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

It works for me when I have a libboost_system.so.1.55.0 dependecy (or any libboost dependency) not meet on system.

Hope it helps!

Comment: According to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-i386/Packages.bz2 that will install Boost 1.58.0 in Ubuntu Wily though. -1